# how to solve composer minimum-stability

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php, sonata-admin

I'm trying to install `Symfony CMF` bundle.

I have installed `SonataAdminBundle 3.x` which requires `SonataBlockBundle 3.x`.

When installing `SymfonyCMF` bundle it requires `symfoy-cmf/block-bundle 1.x`, but this block-bundle requires `SonataBlockBundle 2.5` or less.

I have fork the `symfoy-cmf/block-bundle 1.x` and change the requirement to 3.1 or less.

but I'm still getting following error

> ```
> Problem 1
>     - symfony-cmf/block-bundle 1.3.0 requires sonata-project/block-bundle >=2.2.12,<2.5 -> satisfiable by
> ```
>
> sonata-project/block-bundle[2.2.12, 2.2.13, 2.2.14, 2.2.15, 2.3.0,
>   2.3.1, 2.3.10, 2.3.11, 2.3.12, 2.3.2, 2.3.3, 2.3.4, 2.3.5, 2.3.6, 2.3.7, 2.3.8, 2.3.9] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
>           - symfony-cmf/symfony-cmf 1.3.0 requires symfony-cmf/block-bundle 1.3.* -> satisfiable by
>   symfony-cmf/block-bundle[1.3.0].
>           - Installation request for symfony-cmf/symfony-cmf ~1.3 -> satisfiable by symfony-cmf/symfony-cmf[1.3.0].

composar.json

```
    ...
    "symfony-cmf/symfony-cmf":              "~1.3",
    "iBasit/block-bundle":                  "dev-master", // this is to replace sonata-cmf/block-bundle requirement
    "sonata-project/block-bundle":          "3.0.*",
    ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have got composer dependencies conflict.

I tried to use some ways

- use minimum-stability section
- use conflict section
- install cmf first, before admin bundle
- check ways you tried to do

I made all I knew about the area of your question and I dont see any decision right know.

The best way here is to use minimum-stability section to cmf bundle with "prefer-stable": true flag

I strongly not recommend you to make some changes like "I have fork the symfoy-cmf/block-bundle 1.x and change the requirement to 3.1 or less" because in future it can break dependencies and logic of bundles and it''s hardcode.

Thanks for attention, pls let me know if anyone find the decision of the problem.